cannot get the right results by MathJax on the browser with javascript file
I want to render some formulas with Mathjax even if cutting off internet access.
The detailed html file is as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--  -- -->
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
tex2jax: {
inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre', 'code'],
processEscapes: true
}
});
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
var all = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax();
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i)
all[i].SourceElement().parentNode.className += ' has-jax';
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./MathJax.js"></script>  -->

</head>
<body>
$a_0 = 3^2$
and
$A_{ij} = 2^{i+j}$

</body>
</html>

when the script is linked via 【 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML 】, it is right.
right with MathJax
For I want to use Mathjax even if cutting off internet access, I save the file【 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML 】 as 【MathJax.js】；
then, I use MathJax via 【MathJax.js】, however, the result is totally wrong.
wrong with MathJax
I just use the .js in a different way, and the contents are the same. The result should be the same, is it? Thanks for your kind help!!!

After loading the MathJax script once, the browser subsequently fetches it from its cache. So it would be available even if offline. There is no need to have a local copy. Also it will not work if you load the HTML file via http: but the script via file:. You have not shown us how you do it.

I save the file【 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML 】 as 【MathJax.js】；then I use MathJax via 【 】. Just cancel the annotation, and annotate the 【 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML 】

Please put this additional information into the question itself (use the "Edit" function) rather than in a comment. Does the request for ./MathJax.js succeed? What do you see on the DevTools > Network tab.
